# Combined fading and shading for pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-fadings, tikz-shadings

I am trying to create a background to a pgfplots graph, which has a horizontal shading that also fades from transparent at the bottom to solid colours at the top.

The effect I wish to achieve is illustrated below:

[image]

I can create something close to the background using the code below, but when added to the plot as a background, the plot "collapses", not being laid out correctly.

```
    \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshadingA}
        {5cm}{color(0)=(orange); color(2.5cm)=(white); color(5cm)=(green)} 

    \pgfsetfading{fadeSouth} {\pgftransformscale{4}}
        \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}] {\pgfuseshading{myshadingA}} ;
```

In the attached MWE, I can create the horizontal shading. However, combining that with the transparency eludes me. The fade included seems to do nothing.

An additional challenge I've not been able to solve is how to use rel axis cs to specify the size of the rectangle. At present I've specified the coordinates `\pgfpoint{195}{162}` manually.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a5paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} 
\usepgflibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary {fadings,patterns}
\begin{document}

\tikzfading[name=fadeSouth, top color=transparent!0, bottom color=transparent!100] ;

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshading}{300}
    {color(0bp)=(red); color(25bp)=(orange); color(50bp)=(white); color(75bp)=(green); color(100bp)=(teal)} ;
    


    \begin{axis}[
                    ylabel=Importance,
                    xlabel=State,
                    grid=both,
                    % Fix axis range
                    xmin=-4,
                    xmax=4,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=10,
                    % Set tick marks
                    xtick distance = 1,
                    ytick distance = 1,
                ] 
        \addplot+ [nodes near coords,only marks, point meta=explicit symbolic] 
            table [meta=label] { 
                zState  Importance  label 
                -1.96       7           1
                 1.01       0           2 
                -1.08       3           3 
                -3.37       9           4 
                -0.35       2           5
                 1.38       4           6 
            };
            
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            
            \path [scope fading=fadeSouth ]  (rel axis cs:0,0)  rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1)  ;

            \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{195}{162}}
            \pgfshadepath{myshading}{0}
            \pgfusepath{} ;
            

        \end{scope}

    \end{axis} 
\end {tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, using just `tikz` for the sh/fading. We use 2 rectangles with `color left/right` *and* `path fading=south`. Also, if we shift the scope and match the x/y units of the `tikz` stuff and draw it before `axis`, we basically make a background without any other packages.

I've also added the numbers from your target image just to illustrate the background idea further. You may have to tweak the `axis` more, I'm not a pgfplots person.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
  \begin{scope}[xshift=+4cm]
    \shade[left color=red,  right color=white,path fading=south] (-4,10) rectangle (0,0);
    \shade[left color=white,right color=green,path fading=south] (+4,10) rectangle (0,0);
    \foreach \lt/\lx/\ly in {1/2/7.5,2/2/2.5,3/-2/2.5,4/-2/7.5}{
      \node[black,opacity=.1] at (\lx,\ly) {\Huge\textbf{\lt}}; }
  \end{scope}
  \begin{axis}[x=1cm,y=1cm,
    ylabel=Importance,
    xlabel=State,
    xmin=-4,xmax=+4,
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    grid=both,
    minor y tick num=4,
    minor x tick num=3,
    ytick distance=5,
    xtick distance=4,
    grid style={black,dashed},
    minor grid style={black,dotted}]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks Jesse. The numbers don't match the grid. I'll have a fiddle. And then try adding the data points. If you have any fixes, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The minor tick numbers were one more than necessary. They should be minor y tick num=4, minor x tick num=3. Perhaps you could update the MWE?

Comment: Oop, thanks for that -- I have updated.